# Adding file to zip with php using loop cause damaged zip file

Tags: php, zip

I am adding files to Zip with php using the following php script.

```
<?php
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
session_start();

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
$zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);

$filesinSession = $_SESSION['files'];
$filesToAdd = explode(';', $filesinSession);
for($i = 1 ; $i <= sizeof($filesToAdd)-1 ; $i++)
{
    //echo $filesToAdd[$i]."<br>";
    $zip->addFile($filesToAdd[$i]);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: filename="' . $zip_name . '"');
header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_name));
$zip_file = file_get_contents($zip_name);
readfile($zip_name);
exit();

?>
```

note:session contains file name semicolon separated.

the file generated as a result of above code execution. is damaged when i open that file in sublime text. it shows following error.

///////////////////zip opened in sublime text///////////////////////////////////

**Warning**:  filesize(): stat failed for 1508220713.zip in **C:\xampp\htdocs\HMApp1\download.php** on line **21**

**Warning**:  file_get_contents(1508220713.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\HMApp1\download.php** on line **22**

**Warning**:  readfile(1508220713.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\xampp\htdocs\HMApp1\download.php** on line **23**

Comment: have you enought permissions to create file¿?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón the zip file is created in the same folder where my script lies. But when I try to read that zip for download it throws above three errors.

Comment: then seems php is not localize your .zip file,

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón so what should I do?

Comment: use php to find file first

Comment: have u called $zip->close(); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some classic mistakes in your code, here they are

suppose your session contain files which present in same directory relatively

```
$filesinSession = 'gallery/1/t.jpg;gallery/1/t2.jpg;'; // if ending with ;
```

add trim `$filesToAdd = explode(';', trim($filesinSession, ';'));`

use `0` instead `1`

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($filesToAdd) - 1; $i++) {
```

add local file name during add // best practice

```
$zip->addFile($filesToAdd[$i], basename($filesToAdd[$i]));
```

don't forgot to close

```
$zip->close();
```

fixed header

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zip_name . '"');
```

**removed** `file_get_contents` you don't need it

clean buffer // escape server error

```
ob_end_clean();
flush();
```

Full Source

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = time() . ".zip"; // Zip name
$zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);

$filesinSession = 'gallery/1/t.jpg;gallery/1/t2.jpg;';
$filesToAdd = explode(';', trim($filesinSession, ';'));
for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($filesToAdd) - 1; $i++) {
    $zip->addFile($filesToAdd[$i], basename($filesToAdd[$i]));
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zip_name . '"');
header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_name));
ob_end_clean();
flush();
readfile($zip_name);
exit();
```